# accessing error message in passport js node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

this is my user authentication passport local strategy

```
passport.use(
    new Localstrategy({usernameField:'email'},(email,pass,done)=>{        
        console.log(pass);
        user.findOne({email:email}).then(user=>{
            if(!user){
                return done(null,false,{message:"the email is not registered"})
            }
            bcrypt.compare(pass,user.pass,(err,isMatched)=>{
                if(err){throw err}
                if(isMatched){
                   
                    return done(null,user);
                }
                else{
                    
                    return  done(null,false,{message:"incorrect password"})
                }
            })
        }).catch(e=>console.log(e))
    })
)
```

this is my login route

```
app.post("/login",async function(req,res,next){
    passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect:'/',
        failureRedirect:"/register"
    })(req,res,next);
})
```

i am trying to send the error messages if authentication failed

as you can see from the code i put some messages in case of failure but dont Know how to access them in the route any help?
example:

```
        if(!user){
            return done(null,false,{message:"the email is not registered"})
        }
```

in the above code how to access the message in my failureRedirect route?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this document](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) you can use Flash Messages:

```
passport.use(
  new Localstrategy({usernameField:'email'},(email,pass,done)=>{        
    console.log(pass);
    user.findOne({email:email}).then(user=>{
        if(!user){
            return done(null,false,{message:"the email is not registered"})
        }
        bcrypt.compare(pass,user.pass,(err,isMatched)=>{
            if(err){throw err}
            if(isMatched){
                return done(null,user);
            }
            else{
                return  done(null,false,{message:"incorrect password"})
            }
        })
    }).catch(e=>{
      console.log(e); 
      return done(e);
    })
})
)
```

and route:

```
app.post("/login",passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect:'/',
    failureRedirect:"/register",
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this can be done in many ways, an easy one is:

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local",
       (err, user, options) => {
          if (!user) res.end(options.message)
          console.log(req.body);
          res.end("bla bla")
    })(req, res, next)
}
```